# High charts sunburst text misalignment

Tags: highcharts, sunburst-diagram

I am trying out a sunburst chart using React highcharts and came up with a misalignment issue. If someone has faced this issue before and found a solution, it would be really helpful to me.

Here is the [Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-simple-chart-forked-vbkl95)

Below is the output of the image. Here 'All' text thats displayed in the center seems to be misaligned ( it needs to be moved a bit downwards).

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Misaligned or sitting on the centreline?

Comment: Not sure about that. I thought it should be center to the sunburst instead of sitting on the centreline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest and fastest solution will be to set a proper `dataLabels.y` value based on font-size of current `dataLabel`.

---

**Live demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-simple-chart-forked-inwvzy

**API Reference** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.sunburst.dataLabels.y